# How to get onto AWS Instance from another PC

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have an AWS Linux Instance with a LinuxDemo.pem key. I can access it from my own workstation no problem. But if I try and access it from home or if another colleague tries to we get the following result;

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'LinuxDemo.pem' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: LinuxDemo.pem
Enter passphrase for key 'LinuxDemo.pem':
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Now the same command is ran on all workstations - `ssh -i LinuxDemo.pem ec2-user@<IP_Address>`

How can I make it that a others can access this Instance as this is important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the permissions on your PEM key on the other computers:

```
chmod 0400 LinuxDemo.pem
```

See [Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error)

Comment: I have seen that and tried it, but we still get the same response.

Comment: The error clearly says: `Permissions 0644 for 'LinuxDemo.pem' are too open.` recheck permissions

Comment: And be sure to distribute the private key (LinuxDemo.pem) to your other PCs

Comment: I ran that command on my own PC in the directory where I keep my LinuxDemo.pem key and I forwarded it onto my colleague. He still got the same response

Comment: He should do it on _his own_ computer

Comment: Tried that too with no luck

Comment: Yes, the exact same error that I have in the question

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 Daniel Dold None 1692 Feb 14 14:53 hostkeys\LinuxDemo.pem`

Comment: That's is exactly the problem! it should be `-r-------`! run the `chmod` line on that file, and try again!

Comment: `-r--------+ 1 Administrators None 1692 Feb 14 14:53 LinuxDemo.pem` Like that?

Comment: Just to confirm my colleague is still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

If you dont own the private key. 
Adding it to your ssh agent will do the trick

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add LinuxDemo.pem
ssh user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly states that it has bad permission. All you need to do is change the permission of pem file to 0400 and then try to ssh again.

`chmod 0400 LinuxDemo.pem`