# Connecting to Amazon EC2 Instance on Windows 10 bash - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, windows-10

I am trying to connect to my Amazon EC2 Instance using bash on Windows 10. I have already downloaded MyKey.pem It show me this message

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for 'MyKey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: MyKey.pem
Permission denied (publickey).
```

While searching I found this issue [Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error?rq=1) but didn't help me. I almost followed every single step on [Amazon Documentations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) with no results again.

I tried to change the mode of the key using and didn't work out with me

```
chmod 400 MyKey.pem
```

I also tried to connect using PuTTy but it tells me `server refused our key` 
and shows me this

[image: PuTTy Fatal Error]

How do I fix this?

Comment: try to type your instance ip something like that `ec2-user@[ec2 instance ip]` .

Comment: I tried and it shows me `Name or service not known`

Comment: try this `ssh -i MyKey.pem ec2-user@54.93.162.155` .

Comment: or you can try this too `ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-93-162-155.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Yes, this is the default by AWS. I copied it already from the connect page and still have the same issue. I've been searching and trying many ways to fix this but unfortunately all my tries have been failed. It's wired...

Comment: bro read this article  http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-getting-started-with-amazon-ec2/ hope that helps .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you're storing key file at your usual filesystem. By default Windows 10 don't accept creating 400 permissions at `/mnt/driveletter/blablabla`. If you'll try to do that it'll automatically switch to 555. If you want to configure 400 permissions, you can transfer key file to emulated Linux filesystem. For example to `/home/username` and run `chmod 400 key.pem`. After that ssh to AWS should work as usual.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me on Linux (Through VM).  It seems that I can't use the Ubuntu bash anymore on Windows 10 to access to my EC2 Instance. I

Comment: You can do this by simply going to mykey.pem -> properties -> security -> advance -> remove all users in "Permission Entries" -> add only the user you need to connect from -> Disable Inheritance -> Give full permission