# ssh an Amazon instance permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh

I am a user on my local machine (clientuser1). I ssh into a AWS instance server (with ip: server-ip) as . I have the public key of clientuser1 uploaded in my permission settings. 
I am able to

```
ssh <server-user1>@<server-ip>
```

I, then created a user on the instance,  and tried ssh'ing into the instance:

```
ssh <server-user2>@<server-ip>
```

I got a response:

Permission denied (publickey).

I tried creating a public-private key pair on the  on the server and sent the private key of

```
ssh -i <pvt key of server-user2> <server-user2>@<server-ip>
```

Comment: Is the key with permission 400 on your lical disk? It will deny login if the key is not protect d.

Comment: I do have 400 as the permissions for the identity file

Comment: Check which server user the key needs, sometimes it is ecs2-user, sometimes it is something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error)

Answer (score 1):

For Googlers:

Other than the common permission-related causes, if the system disk is full, SSH server will also respond "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked was

```
ssh-add <id_rsa>
```

This added the new key to `ssh-agent`.