# Permission denied (publickey).while copying ssh key to server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keygen

I am getting *`Permission denied (publickey)`* error while copying a public key using this command over ec2 ubuntu instance

```
root@ip-172-31-5-68:~# ssh-copy-id docadmin@ip-172-31-13-212

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed:"/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys

docadmin@ip-172-31-13-212: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone help me why I am getting this permission issue?

Answer (score -1):

**AWS doesn't allow SSH connections to an EC2 instance with private keys that are publicly exposed.**

While you're trying to copy a `.pub` (public key) over to instance 2, you're using `ssh-copy-id`, which [uses `ssh` under the hood to facilitate the transfer](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id), so you'll first need to lock down your private key on instance 1.

Substituting the last term for your private key `.pem` filepath, you can accomplish this with:

`chmod 400 /path/to/your-private-key.pem`

---

The following post seems to be the canonical reference for this topic, but this is a slightly different scenario, so I'm not going to mark it as a duplicate:

- [Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193768/trying-to-ssh-into-an-amazon-ec2-instance-permission-error)